# Operator[] overloading using friend function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, friend-function

Why isn't it possible to overload the subscript operator (operator[]) as a friend function?

Comment: You should probably add a language tag (I guess `c++` from the `friend-function` tag's description) so that you question receives more attention.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bjarne Stroustrup says in the [D&E book](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html):

> However, even in the original design of C++, I restricted operators `[]`, `()`, and `->` to be members. It seemed a harmless restriction that eliminated the possibility of some obscure errors because these operators invariably depend on and typically modify the state of their left-hand operand. However, it is probably a case of unnecessary nannyism.

Answer (score 0):

[Friends](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) are not extensions to your class, just a keyword saying xy has access to your class's private or protected members. You can not override or add functions this way.

> The friend declaration appears in a class body and grants a function or another class access to private and protected members of the class where the friend declaration appears.

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend)